# Android - изменение цвета текста на кнопке

Tags: xml, text, android, button, color

Здравствуйте. Есть много кнопок с установленным на них бэкграундом. Помню, что используя xml, можно было менять бэкграунд на другие изображения, при нажатии/фокусировке на кнопку. Вопрос: как можно сделать так (используя xml), чтобы при нажатии/фокусировке на кнопку менялся цвет текста на ней? Помню ещё, что надо было где-то создать стиль, а в нём прописывать selector..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="…" />
    <item android:color="…" />
</selector>
```

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    …
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector" />
```

Comment: @falstaf, Как всегда в точку! спасибо за ответ!